# Secondary voltage spike in flyback transformer

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback, snubber, switching-transients

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWaJ3V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using a TNY264 IC to make a custom flyback transformer. (U1 is the TNY264.)

The primary to secondary turns ratio is 10 with the primary inductance being 6mH.

I am using the standard design of flyback topology suggested by TNY264 datasheet without any bias winding.

The output is regulated at close to 13 volts using two 6.2V Zeners in series with an optocoupler providing feedback. (I used an LED and photodiode in the schematic to represent this as I couldn't find an optocoupler.)

The issue is as follows:

Large voltage spikes occur at the secondary when the switch is opened or when "flyback" occurs.

[image: Blue - Drain voltage Yellow - output Voltage]

Blue -Drain voltage, yellow -output voltage
The ringing caused by the leakage inductance is reflected onto the secondary.

I have clamped the drain with a RCD snubber, which peaks the drain voltage at 164V.

The nominal value of drain after the ringing stops is about 130 volts which is in agreement with the turns ratio. The circuit is working in DCM mode.

How can I stop the voltage spikes on the secondary? Should the primary snubber network be improved?

Comment: How good is your oscilloscope probing method? And, can you put some numbers on the spike you see (presumably the yellow trace where light blue is primary?). Also 200,000 farads is not an acceptable clamp capacitor value.

Comment: [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSo3N.jpg) for correct probing to avoid false readings. You can check how good your present probing is by shorting the probe tip to your ground clip and see what the scope voltage looks like. I bet it looks pretty similar to your pictures above. Put some numbers on the spike voltage - do I have to repeat myself????

Comment: I shorted the probe ground and tip as you suggested there is only an steady DC offset voltage of about 10mV. I think the probing is not the issue.

Comment: Were you connecting to 0 volts on the target circuit when you did that i.e. did you simultaneously short the probe to the earth wire whilst the earth wire is connected to 0 volts on the secondary?

Comment: You may be exceeding oscilloscope's dynamic range...zero volts is far, far below the screen bottom. Although display says "500mV/div" the means value is 13.2V DC. Try backing-off to a lower scale, and see if the waveshape persists. Or switch to AC coupling to block that large, potentially disturbing 13.2V.

Comment: @Andy sorry i misunderstood your previous method. I did as you suggested i can see a the voltage spike of the wave form on the grounded probe and it is also slighlty leading the the actual output voltage.But the magnitude of the grounded probe is of 20-30 millivolts only.Also the peak of the spike of the output voltage is 14.1V

Comment: Add a bunch of 10uF ceramic caps in parallel to C2. Electrolytic caps have a slow response and inductive effects.

Comment: I saw this problem at my flyback design. I add a capacitor in parallel to Vin and solved. You had better try this method in my opinion.

Comment: The 1N4007 diode you have used is not really recommended because of potentially its high reverse recovery time. The data sheet recommends a 1N4937 - try that out. It's potentially a hundred times quicker than the 400x range of diodes. Also, the [data sheet](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/tny263_268.pdf) shows C3 being present but your circuit does not. Have you fitted this part?

Comment: The diode could be the problem. Due to late turn on of the diode the snubber is not able to supress the leakage inductance induced spike. Are you reffering to the snubber capacitor or bypass capacitor of the ic as C3

Comment: C3 in the data sheet connected to BP. You don't have a C3.

Comment: Did you use C3 @FarvezFarook

Comment: Yes i did, i have not added that in the schematic

Comment: Did you sort this out @FarvezFarook - if you did maybe you can leave your own answer explaining the fix/solution?